# iOS 11.2.1 Xcode 9.2 BoringSSL SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN(6)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm hitting this error all of a sudden in my project that has a WKWebView displaying a page. The page loads fine like it used to. But now when I attempt to navigate to another page from that page, I get this error:

```
[BoringSSL] Function boringssl_session_errorlog: line 2871 [boringssl_session_read] SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN(6): operation failed because the connection was cleanly shut down with a close_notify alert
```

It seems like it's related to my pc / device as I've never hit this before.

A few things I found said I need to make sure I have the other linked flag set to -ObjC. Also setting Allows Arbitrary Loads to Yes. Both of those are set and the error continues.

The web page is using TLS 1.2.

Comment: I see this regularly also.  It doesn't seem to affect the performance of the app.

Comment: I have the same issue too. The apple developer forums are entirely unhelpful. We need a step-by-step process to solve this once and for all.

Comment: Check this: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/95206

Comment: maybe its server side security (https) issue or backend side need to updated SSL Certificate... **found this message from other stackoverflow link** - From openssl documentation openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/SSL_get_error.html: "SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN: The TLS/SSL connection has been closed. If the protocol version is SSL 3.0 or higher, this result code is returned only if a closure alert has occurred in the protocol, i.e. if the connection has been closed cleanly. Note that in this case SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN does not necessarily indicate that the underlying transport has been closed."

Answer (score 1):

The exact reason for the error shown can't be determined without more detailed logging.

`CFNetwork` handles the core of `Foundation`’s networking classes — It also has the (often overlooked) capability of detailed logging via the **`CFNETWORK_DIAGNOSTICS`** environment variable.

**Programmatically enabling `CFNetwork` diagnostic logging**:

```
setenv("CFNETWORK_DIAGNOSTICS", "3", 1);
```

It should be set to an integer value from 0 to 3, where 0 is off and higher numbers give progressively more logging. During normal development you can set this environment variable via Xcode’s scheme editor. When the app is run from Xcode, the `CFNetwork` log entries will appear in the debug console area (if not visible, choose `View` > `Debug Area` > `Show Debug Area`).

The environment variable should be placed right at the beginning of the app’s launch sequence. Normally putting this at the start of main is sufficient, but if you have C++ static initialisers that use `CFNetwork` you’ll have to put it before those.

> **Note**: In Swift this code would go in `main.swift`. By default Swift apps
>   don’t have a `main.swift`; “[The Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Attributes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH35-ID347)” explains how
>   to add one.
>   <sub>*Also note, in Swift remove the semi-colon at the end of the `setenv`.</sub>

Setting the environment variable above should definitely help in determining where the issue is, or at the very least give you a starting point to begin diagnosing a somewhat vague error message.

↳ [CFNetwork Diagnostic Logging](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1887/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40015177-CH1-SECLOGGINGWITHOUTXCODE)

Comment: Can't get it to go to no warnings at app.setenv("CFNETWORK_DIAGNOSTICS", "3", 1); produces a very long warning report and setenv("CFNETWORK_DIAGNOSTICS", "0", 0); brings me back to start situation. Maybe just let it log, seemd to be happy!