# IOS Offline Caching WebView content

Tags: ios, caching, webview, offline

I need to load an url in a `WebView` and download the whole content of the website (documents, images, css, etc) to be able to work offline.

I built an app 4-5 years ago (targeting iOS 7.0) using this --> http://robnapier.net/offline-uiwebview-nsurlprotocol

Recently I was asked to check if the app still works for the latest iOS versions. I found that most of the classes mentioned in this article are deprecated now (for example: `UiWebView` or `NSURLConnection`).

When I run the app now, the caching process starts but it gets stuck at some point while downloading a file.

I've enabled `CFNETWORK DIAGNOSTICS` and most of the time I get this error: `SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN operation failed because the connection was cleanly shut down with a close_notify alert`. I've researched a lot without any success.

I'm thinking about rebuilding the whole app using a modern solution, but actually I don't really find anything clear. Probably it is not common to do these kind of apps.

My question is if someone nows a better approach for this. I don't even care if I do it natively on `iOS` or using some cross-platform technology like `Reac-Native` or `Flutter`.

Any suggestions would be very welcome.

Thanks.

**EDIT**

The web that I have to wrap inside the `WebView` implements a `Service Worker` to cache the data. So in a `Safari` browser, this web works offline.

I would just need to wrap someone this web in an iOS app, I tried `SFSafariViewController` but still not working.

[SFSafariViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/sfsafariviewcontroller)

Answer (score 1):

Deprecated doesn't mean unavailable. There are still plenty of apps using `UIWebView` and `NSURLConnection`. Before you go rewriting your app using the latest and greatest, you should understand what the problem is. There's a good tip for debugging the error you're getting in [*iOS 11.2.1 Xcode 9.2 BoringSSL SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN(6)*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48971813/643383). Short version: set the `CFNETWORK_DIAGNOSTICS` environment variable so that you get better network debugging information.

Given the age of your code, I'd imagine that [Apple's requirement that apps use secure connections](https://techcrunch.com/2016/06/14/apple-will-require-https-connections-for-ios-apps-by-the-end-of-2016/) starting in iOS 9 might be at least one factor. You should read up on [App Transport Security](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW33) to learn how to update your app to meet those requirements. You'll definitely need to add a key or two to your app's `Info.plist` file, and you'll probably also want to update your app to use a `https` URL instead of `http`. Making these changes will be much easier than rewriting your app, and you need to meet the ATS requirement anyway, so you might as well do that part first.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Caleb, I really appreciate it :) I've already set the `CFNETWORK_DIAGNOSTICS` as I said in my post. 

I didn't mention it but I've also added the `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` and `NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads ` to my `Info.plist` and use `https`.

After doing everything I could find, it still not works. I think it has something to do with the fact that the website used Application Cache for caching the offline data, and now it was updated to use a Service Worker